# Hide node created messages programmatically

Tags: 7, status-messages

I'm trying to the node created messages for a certain content type, but I can't use Disable Messages because it has a conflict the Commerce Add to Cart Confirmation module.

All the other methods ([like the ones here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928131/disable-drupal-content-creation-message)) I've found either hide all status messages, or hide all status messages after a content type is created, which are inappropriate for me since I'm using rules to show a messages after a node is created, but I need to hide the default "__________ has been created" message, and I appreciate any help you can offer me.

Answer (score 7):

[`drupal_set_message`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) is not hookable. But the message you want removed comes from [`node_form_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7), so you can get rid of it using [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) on [`node_form`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7). Either replace [`node_form_submit`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7) as form's submit handler with it's clone, sans messages, or set second handler that will remove what you want removed from `$_SESSION['messages'][$type]`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide me with more information? I've never used $_SESSION['messages'][$type] before. I've been looking for information for 4 days but I'm still not sure of what to do, or I'm looking at the wrong places. I've found information that doesn't support replacing node_form_submit with a clone which was why I prefer using $_SESSION['messages'][$type].

Comment: Look at [answer by Parvind](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/123051/16495) - it is *almost* OK. Just, instead of `unset($_SESSION['messages']);`, use `var_dump` or `kpr` to see what's in it. Then you will know what exactly you are looking for to unset. For your particular situation `$type = 'status'`, so just unset last element of `$_SESSION['messages']['status']` if it's what you don't want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

While I was searching for solutions before I received the helpful reply from Mołot, I've found this module that fits my needs: [Custom Submit Messages](https://www.drupal.org/project/csm)

It allows me to customise or remove any node creation, update, or deletion message in the content type->edit form.

(I had to disable messages displayed with Rules "*After a node is created*" to make it work as intended)

I appreciate your time and advice, but I've decided to go ahead with this because I plan to modify many more messages, the way this module allows and it will allow me to save a lot of time from doing it programatically.

Comment: I cannot mark this as the answer because the title of the question pertains to hiding the messages *programmatically*, although the reason for me to want to do it programatically was because I have a module conflict with the **Disable Messages** module and I couldn't find another module which can hide messages, nor did I think about formulating the problem in another way, i.e. "How to customize messages", which was what I was doing earlier with Disable Messages and Rules.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish this programmatically is to insert `drupal_get_messages('status');` after you call your save function.

```
$wrapper->save();
drupal_get_messages('status');
drupal_set_message('New Custom Message... or no message at all'));
```

Note that ANY status messages will be caught by this, not just the one generated by the save function, so use it cautiously as it may have unattended affects.

Comment: This is wayyyyyy better than overriding the whole node submit hook. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Molot's answer concerning unsetting certain elements of $_SESSION['messages'] in an additional form submit handler was the best solution for me. One thing I struggled with was adding the custom handler appropriately -- not just to $form['#submit'][]. The following code works great for me:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_FORM_ID_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MY_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_remove_message';
}

function MY_MODULE_NODE_TYPE_remove_message(&$form, &$form_state) {
  foreach ($_SESSION['messages']['status'] as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value, 'STRING UNWANTED MESSAGE BEGINS WITH') === 0) {
        unset($_SESSION['messages']['status'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while researching how to hide the status update message in Drupal 9. The answers here have been deprecated as of 8.5+ in favor of \Drupal::messenger().

Into your custom module:

```
function HOOK_form_alter (array &$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'NODE_ID') {
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'MY_SUBMIT_FUNCTION';
}
}

function MY_SUBMIT_FUNCTION($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$messenger = \Drupal::messenger();
$messenger->deleteByType($messenger::TYPE_STATUS);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function custommodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "article_node_form") {
    //For article content type
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custommodule_custom_submit';
  }
}

function custommodule_custom_submit() {
  if (in_array("sellers", $user->roles)) {
    //sellers - For specific user role
    unset($_SESSION['messages']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unsetting all messages is not a clean solution. It destroys messages created by other modules, too, and may mask errors user should be notified about immediately.

Comment: See [this comment](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/123045/hide-node-created-messages-programmatically/123047?noredirect=1#comment147353_123047) and feel free to use it to make your answer perfect :)

Answer (score -2):

http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/729

Change

```
$_SESSION['messages']['status'][$old_message_key] = 'Текст нового сообщения';
```

to

```
unset($_SESSION['messages']['status'][$old_message_key]);
```